# Adding a div around a menu with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been bashing my head at this very simple task. I have a nested  list for a drop down menu, I need to add a div AROUND the second  so it will work with a framework that wants to see this. I can do it a number of ways that seem really dumb. Anyone have a nice clean way to do it? So, I have this:

```
<ul class="nav_menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="drop_men">Men</a></li>
          ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="rates"><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
    ....
  </ul>
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
<ul class="nav_menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
       <div class="add this div here">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="drop_men">Men</a></li>
          ...
        </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="rates"><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
    ....
  </ul>
```

Comment: _"I can do it a number of ways that seem really dumb."_ Please post what you've tried so we can see the effort, and not duplicate what you've tried.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Could you show one of the "dumb" methods you have tried so far? Maybe we can improve on that?

Comment: Thanks all. Right after I wrote this question it occurred to me that this has got to be one of the most stupidly common things to do with Jquery and there would have to be some sort of really easy way to do it, and of course there is. Duh duh duh. GAH! Lower my reputation to -6 and keep me away from electrical appliances.

L

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
$(".nav_menu li:first ul").wrap("<div class=''></div>");
```